# Checking for insects in the home?

Tags: carpet, uk, insect

We are about to move into our new home and it looks like the carpet had never been cleaned so we decided a new one would be best.

I took up the carpet yesterday, and today I have a few bug bites on my body, which I am assuming was caused by something on the carpet.

What can I do to check if there are insects still where the carpet was, and what can I do to make sure they don't just move into the new carpet?

Comment: If this isn't covered by this stack just let me know and I'll get rid of it.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Trapper-Insect-Great-Spiders-Cockroaches/dp/B002Y6JHES

Answer (score 1):

The most common insect that readily makes it's our casa it's casa is the flea. Fleas find an ideal environment in our rugs. They can also go without food for many days. They can lay thousand of eggs in their life-cycle. Whats amazing is that the eggs, once deposited in the naps of a carpet will remain un-hatched until it senses vibration (from humans walking) signaling that dinner has arrived.

To verify that there is an infestation place a white bed sheet on the ground outside. Holding a section of the rug over it shake vigorously for a few seconds. You should now have a clear look at everything that resided in the carpet.

If you are certain the marks are not a skin re-action to a substance on the rug, but was caused by a blood-sucking insect, have a professional insect eradicator access the situation and prescribe a treatment. They are best at knowing what and how to remove the pest that may be residing in your home.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The marks are in areas which would not have made contact.  Is your answer about the UK?

Comment: My answer pertains to all countries that have fleas as a pest.